# How can I resolve this issue

Tags: react-native

When I run the application the server gives me error code 500.

[image]

Comment: Hey Dinesh, welcome in StackOverflow, we can't give you a solution without seeing your code so edit your question and provide some details and your code

Comment: Please give the question that really needs solution. https://www.i-programmer.info/news/99-professional/12044-stack-overflow-adopts-new-code-of-conduct-.html

Answer (score 2):

This error mostly happens when the server-side is gone off. Ex: you run your code on some port and your program (website, application) listens to it and all of a sudden server stops running for some reason. you might wanna re-run your code. Please upload some of your code next time